# Complete definition of logical connectives and quantifiers?

Tags: semantics, logic

The list of logical connectives might be subject to debate, but what do you think is the most complete one? For English language and computational logic.

I'm looking to implement a semantical analysis program and I need it to identify sentences structured "around" logical connectives and quantifiers such as "and", "or", "any", "each", "all". I'm looking for a listing that's complete enough to allow for the "classifications" of parts of sentences according to how they are "connected" or how they have been related to other parts.

An example sentence is

> [A] fish is [any] [member of] a paraphyletic [group of] organism[s] that [consist of] [all] gill- bearing aquatic craniate animal[s] that lack limb[s] [with] digit[s].

where those parts in brackets [ ] are examples of connectives or quantifiers that I'd like to be able to spot.

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics SE! You should specify if you are looking for English connectives, specifically. Because otherwise just take all that logic supplies traditionally (like **and, or, therefore**).

Comment: English or logical as I don't know whether these would be found under logic or under "English linguistics".

Comment: What I'm trying to say is, you will have different words in different languages, and they will have different semantics, and at least some of them will not spell out exactly logical operators (but rather have certain pragmatics around them). So you still need to clarify what you're interested in :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know what your experience with data structures and programming is, but logical connectives as you know them are probably what you know as binary operators in logic and mathematics. As the name implies, you need two elements and some operation or relation can be shown by connectives/symbols.

Having said that, I think you can find useful information in for example Chapter 10 of the book "Semantics" by John Saeed. It is the book I had for my Semantics 1 course. I trust there are more books out there that discuss the same problems, but currently I do not know many.

What you are trying is not exactly an attempt at something new and the branch that deals with these problems is, amongst others, predicate logic (see also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IhodKMPwShc : "SEM122 - Predicate Logic I"). However, there are numerous problems with your example sentence. There is for example not a connective for "a". In predicate logic this is dealt with by stating sets and assigning predicates to constants (entities) within models. For example in some model M: "there is an x and x is a fish and x is a paraphyletic entity", etc. As you can see, this can only be done by a very dynamic program, because at any point you will have to denote new sets. It is very strong, but a very heinous job as well. And this is only for declarative sentences such as your example sentence.

What you were looking for was a list of connectives and I shortly discussed why there is no such list. I am not trying to discourage you, but it is not an easy task. Above is just a suggestion for an approach to solve the problem you needed the list for in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Determiners:: Logical quantifiers: some, few, more, most, many, much, each, every, any, all.  Cardinal quantifiers: 0(no), 1(a[n]), 2 ...  Indexical determiners: the, both, [n]either, next, previous, prior, last.  Ordinals: 1st, 2nd ...  You also bracketed the plural 's', which quantifies 'any', 'some' and 'the'. Your other brackets mark coordinating conjunctions: and, [n]or, but.  You should then consider subordinate conjunctions: if, as, because, so, before, after, when, while, unless ...; but that opens the door to many adverbials: where, how, during ...  I think you go too far now with bracketing associative prepositions (with, of ...), collection related nouns (group, member ...) and collection related verbs (consist, [have]...).